# Spring boot WebApplication starts twice on Tomcat 7 server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7, server.xml

I have Spring boot WebApplication, that I can start separately in without having Tomcat installed, because it has embedded Server in itself, right?
So is starts normally when I right-click on it in Eclipse and choose: RunAs/SpringBootApp

[image: Starts once]

But when I add it Tomcat 7 server.xml is starts twice. So I assuming that firstly it starts with his embedded Server and then it tries to start in Tomcat 7?

[image: Starts twice]

Here are the logs:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat7dev\webapps\enlivenweb
Apr 25, 2016 10:49:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/enlivenweb]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1897)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManager@57239838] with key 'environmentManager'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:678)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Have you followed the [traditional deployment guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) for Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, spring-boot-starter-tomcat has <scope>provided</scope> in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

In case the `management.port` is configured differently from the `server.port` a second embedded servlet container is spun up. You can't use these two options when doing a traditional war-file deployment.